# Find duplicate values in an array

Tags: arrays, powershell

i have the following code:

```
cls
Get-Module -ListAvailable | Import-Module
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like 'XYZ'} | select name - 
ExpandProperty name
$i=0 
$tot = $Groups.count 
$Table = @()

$Record = @{
"Group Name" = ""
"Name" = ""
"username" = ""
}

Foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
#// Set up progress bar 
$i++ 
$status = "{0:N0}" -f ($i / $tot * 100) 
Write-Progress -Activity "Exporting AD Groups" -status "Processing 
Group $i of $tot : $status% Completed" -PercentComplete ($i / $tot * 
100) 
$Arrayofmembers = Get-ADGroupMember -identity $Group -recursive | 
select name, SamAccountName
foreach ($Member in $Arrayofmembers) {
$Record."Group Name" = $Group
$Record."Name" = $Member.name
$Record."username" = $Member.SamAccountName
$objRecord = New-Object PSObject -property $Record
$Table += $objrecord

}
 }
Write-Host $Table
```

which works perfectly but i want to list all duplicates in the $Record."Name" = $Member.name with specific group so for example:

username=barry is duplicated in GROUP XYZ

i tried already the following:

```
ForEach ($Element in $Table)
{
If (($Table -match $Element).count -gt 1)
{
    "Duplicates detected" 

}
}
```

Comment: Please include [mcve], not full code in your question. It'd be far more readable for people trying to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply keep track of the members using a hashtable:

```
$seen = @{};
foreach ($Member in $Arrayofmembers)
{
    if($seen[$Member.Name])
    {
        Write-Host "$($Member.Name) is duplicated in group $Group";
    }
    else
    {
        $seen.Add($Member.Name, $true);
    }

    # ... rest of the loop
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The simplest answer is to just pipe `$Table` to `Group-Object` and filter for groups with a count greater than one at the end as such:

```
$Table | Group 'Group Name','Name' | Where{$_.Count -gt 1}
```

If you are looking to do this in the middle of your loop you could do so by grouping the results of Get-ADGroupMember, but I think it'll probably be faster to do it all at the end.